# c# Bruteforce generate HeX Values

Tags: c#, brute-force

So The Last Few Days I've Been Doing A Normal C# Console Application to brute force a specific key structure

My Problem Is That im trying to create a brute force Application That Can Continue From The Already Known Keys

in this Case i know that the starting keys are

> 00000001008500

I'm trying to only brute force the final parts of the key to get the final key as

> 000000010085000B14187441FFC3EC0B

The Problem is that instead of adding the next charterer e.g.

> 000000010085001
>
> 000000010085002

it does this

> 000000010085001000000010085002

any advice would be of much help

The Code I'm Using Is as follow

```
//define likely password characters
    static char[] Match =  {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};
    //your password
    static string FindPassword;
    static int Combi;
    static string space;        

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        space = " ";
        int Count;
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to BRUTE FORCE ");
        Console.WriteLine(space);

        FindPassword = "000000010085000B14187441FFC3EC0B";

        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss");
        Console.WriteLine(space);
        Console.WriteLine("START:\t{0}", today);
        for (Count = 0; Count <= 15; Count++)
        {
            Recurse(Count, 0, "");
        }
    }

    static void Recurse(int Lenght, int Position, string BaseString)
    {
        int Count = 0;

        for (Count = 0; Count < Match.Length ; Count++)
        {
            Combi++;
            if (Position < Lenght - 1)
            {
                Recurse(Lenght, Position + 1, "00000001008500"+BaseString + Match[Count]);
            }
            if (BaseString + Match[Count] == FindPassword)
            {
                DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
                today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss");
                Console.WriteLine(space);
                Console.WriteLine("END:\t{0}\nCombi:\t{1}", today, Combi);
                Console.WriteLine(BaseString.ToString() + Match[Count]);
                Console.ReadLine();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: I't goes into an endless loop because instead of adding the next values it does this       **000000010085001000000010085002**    instead of   **000000010085001** //  **000000010085002**

Comment: That's normal, that's what your code do `"00000001008500"+BaseString + Match[Count]`

Comment: I think you shouldn't be doing this with strings... it is too slow. Try with an array of bytes instead; or even better: a couple of `UInt64`s.

Comment: @Thomas @ Leandro Taset How Would U Suggest i handle this type of brute force

Comment: Are you trying to apply bruteforce an hexadecimal number with length of 18? You must know there are many many combinations (16 posibilites for position)

Comment: @dbvega yes i am trying to brutefoce the last 18 hex decimal characters

Comment: It's 18^16 cases. It's [121.439.531.096.594.251.776](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=18^16) cases. You'll be dead before the end, even with the correct code

Comment: yes @Thomas that's I mean.

Comment: @dbvega (I know, I just wanted to make him realize :) )

Comment: with a 2.5Ghz I loop through 1.000.000.000 numbers in 3 seconds. Even with a 8 core parallel 2.5Ghz, it would take 1500 years

Comment: @Thomas Interesting how I thought this seemed like a very viable problem that could be done and was trying to find the error until I read your comment. Some math goes a longgg way.